# Writing operator in its eigenbase

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a ""paradox"" that I don't know how to solve.

I have an operator $G$ where $G(x,x')=\langle x|G|x'\rangle $

I can write $G(x,x')$ in two differents ways that are not equivalent and I don't see my mistake. I call $\{\Psi_n\}$ the family of eigenvectors of $G$.

First way of writing :

$$G(x,x')=\sum_{n,m} \langle x|\Psi_n\rangle \langle \Psi_n|G|\Psi_m\rangle \langle \Psi_m|x'\rangle $$
$$G(x,x')=\sum_{n,m} \lambda_m \langle x|\Psi_n\rangle \langle \Psi_n|\Psi_m\rangle \langle \Psi_m|x'\rangle $$

Second way :

$$G(x,x')=\sum_{n} \lambda_n \langle x|\Psi_n\rangle \langle \Psi_n|x'\rangle $$

In the second way I just write the matrix where the eigenvalues are on the diagonal.

I don't understand why in my second writing it assumes that I have an orthogonal basis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your two expressions are the same if $G$ is selfadjoint (more properly, normal). In that case, the $\Psi_n$ are an orthonormal basis, and you have
$$
\langle \Psi_n|\Psi_m\rangle=\delta_{n,m}.
$$
When $G$ is not normal, you cannot even write the first expression, as the eigenvalues do not have to show in $G(x,x')$.

Comment: I agree that if $G$ is normal my eigenvectors can be chosen as orthonormal, so the two expressions are equivalents.

So if I understand you well, I can't write the first expression if $G$ is not normal because If it is the case, if i say $|\Psi_n>$ form a base of my space, all of them can't also be eigenvectors of $G$ (because elsewhere it would mean that $G$ is normal and we have contradiction).

Am I right ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Almost. When $G$ is not normal you may have a basis of eigenvectors, but not an orthonormal one. In general, you don't even have a basis of eigenvectors, for instance when $$G=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: In fact I thought I understood but I don't.

If G is not normal, why would my first expression be wrong. Indeed $G|\Psi_m>=\lambda_m |\Psi_m>$. Why do you say I can't write this if G is not normal.

Isn't my second expression only right if my eigenvectors are orthogonals  (if I assume G is diagonal in $|\Psi>$ base) ? Because $|\Psi_n><\Psi_n|$ contains a 1 at n'th line and n'th column only if my base composed of my $|\Psi>$ vectors is orthogonal ? (Because $<\Psi_i|\Psi_n><\Psi_n|\Psi_j>$ can be non 0 if $i \neq j$ if my base is not orthogonal).

Comment: What you are missing is that when $G$ is not normal, there may not be enough eigenvectors. For the concrete $G$ in my previous comment, both your sums are zero.

Comment: Ah yes you are write. I have a little forgotten the basis of linear algebra